# Creating a hierarchy group from one table column contain both parent and child hierarchy info

Tags: sql-server-2008, parent-child, hierarchy

I need help creating a hierarchy group 'using' the data in **Event_Role** column in my sample table to create a grouping structure like below.

The 6 parent hierarchies which are

```
'Speaker', 'Coordinator', 'Volunteer', 'Instructor', 'Attendee', 'Registration'
```

And the child hierarchies (or lower levels) are

```
Did Not Attend/Yes Attend for Attendee and Do Not Register/No Reg/Yes Reg for Registration.
```

I have 100000+ rows to create these hierarchy groups for and I have more groups and child hierarchies.

**hierarchy Groups**

```
Speaker     
Coordinator     
Volunteer       
Instructor      
Attendee---   **child(Lv2)**-- Did Not Attend/Yes Attend
Registration--**child(Lv2)**---Do Not Register/No Reg/Yes Reg
```

I have create the sample data in SQL Server

Thank you in advance!!

```
Create table table1
(
Participant_ID int not null
,Supporter_ID int not null
,Event_Code varchar (50)
,Event_Role varchar (100) null
)

INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234221','23536','LEG_SWI_1995','Did Not Attend');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234221','23536','LEG_SWI_1995','Yes Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234220','17238','LEG_SWI_1995','Did Not Attend');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234220','17238','LEG_SWI_1995','Yes Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234219','23532','LEG_HAT_1996','Did Not Attend');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234219','23532','LEG_HAT_1996','Yes Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234218','58195','LEG_HAT_1996','Did Not Attend');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234218','58195','LEG_HAT_1996','Yes Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234217','23494','LEG_SWI_1995','Did Not Attend');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234217','23494','LEG_SWI_1995','Yes Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234208','00442','LEG_OXF_1998','Yes Attended');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234182','65306','SWCM01','IsCoordinator');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234182','65306','SWCM01','No Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234152','22969','LEG_HAT_1996','IsCoordinator');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234152','22969','LEG_HAT_1996','No Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234146','32672','LEG_MAR_01','IsCoordinator');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234146','32672','LEG_MAR_01','No Reg');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234123','47377','LEG_OXF_1998','Yes Attended');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234122','38726','LEG_OXF_1998','Yes Attended');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('234121','50341','LEG_BUR_0000','Yes Attended');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218893','90409','SEMF091212','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218890','23749','RFSEAH091212','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218889','90387','SEAJ251112','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218884','65306','SERB031212','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218874','58902','SECW021212','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218231','50766','LM1301','Do Not Register');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218221','73854','SEGF050912','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218218','28146','LM1301','Do Not Register');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('218211','95575','SEDB220712','Speaker');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('217647','22632','GNR0001','Do Not Register');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('142470','08862','ELON09','IsVolunteer');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('142469','01362','ELON09','IsVolunteer');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Participant_ID,Supporter_ID,Event_Code,Event_Role) VALUES ('132899','92898','ELON09','IsVolunteer');
```

`

Comment: For presenting data like this I would recommend you create an example at SqlFiddle.com    it will help your cause.    Next can you show what you expect the output to be as your explanation leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Look this [SqlFiddleLink](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9adc8/11) maybe helps you friend.
I have created another table **Group_EventRole** for your **hierarchy group** or (hierarchy Type in my idea) and I altered your table1's Event_Role column to **int** too.

the **Name** is your **Event_Role** and also the **Name_Parent** is the parent of your  **Event_Role**